# XPath using starts-with function

Tags: xpath

I'm writing Java on Android to retrieve data from XML file, but I've got a problem.  Consider this XML:

```
<ITEM>
   <REVENUE_YEAR>2554-02</REVENUE_YEAR>
   <REGION>Central</REGION>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
  <REVENUE_YEAR>2552-02</REVENUE_YEAR>
  <REGION>Central</REGION>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
  <REVENUE_YEAR>2552-03</REVENUE_YEAR>
  <REGION>Central</REGION>
</ITEM>
```

How can I get all  elements in years that start-with 2552. I tried:

```
//REVENUE_YEAR[starts-with(.,'2552')]/text()
```

It works, but when I tried:

```
//REVENUE_YEAR[starts-with(.,'2552')]/REGION/text()
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 53):

Use:

```
/*/ITEM[starts-with(REVENUE_YEAR,'2552')]/REGION
```

**Note**: Unless your host language can't handle element instance as result, do not use text nodes specially in mixed content data model. Do not start expressions with `//` operator when the schema is well known.

Comment: I don't get it...why use /*/ again?  I just had a similar problem with XPath in Selenium and I added the * instead of my initial // and it works also: GetByxPath(string.Format("/*/tbody[@id='someContainer']/tr/td[1]/a(starts-with(@href, {0})", "/Customers/"));

Comment: Speed.  // is very slow.  You always want to search down from the top if you can because it is much faster.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
//REVENUE_YEAR[starts-with(.,'2552')]/../REGION/text()
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
//ITEM/*[starts-with(text(),'2552')]/following-sibling::*
```

Comment: An answer with explanation, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5705866/1677912) is better (and gets more votes) than a simple "try this" like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17786221/1677912).