# Read xml category name xmllistmodel

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, qml

I am trying to read a category name of an xml and get it's type.

Xml looks like this:

```
<subtitledelay>0</subtitledelay>
        <equalizer/><information>
                <category name="meta">
                        <info name="title">
                                The Movie
                        </info>
                        <info name="filename">
                                The Movie
                        </info>
                        </category>
                <category name="Stream 0">
                        <info name="Type">Video</info>
                        <info name="Frame rate">23.976215</info>
                        <info name="Decoded format">Planar 4:2:0 YUV</info>
                        <info name="Codec">H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)</info>
                        <info name="Language">English</info>
                        <info name="Resolution">1024x542</info>
                </category>
                <category name="Stream 1">
                        <info name="Bitrate">384 kb/s</info>
                        <info name="Type">Audio</info>
                        <info name="Channels">3F2R/LFE</info>
                        <info name="Sample rate">48000 Hz</info>
                        <info name="Language">Russian</info>
                        <info name="Codec">A52 Audio (aka AC3) (a52 )</info>
                </category>
                <category name="Stream 6"><info name="Description">Full</info>
                        <info name="Type">Subtitle</info>
                        <info name="Language">English</info>
                        <info name="Codec">Text subtitles with various tags (subt)</info>
                        </category>
                <category name="Stream 3">
```

And I am trying to read the category name of the stream in this case stream 0, 1, 6 and 3 and find out it's type.

I can get the type if I pass the stream name

```
 XmlRole{ name: "type"; query: "information/category[@name='Stream 0']/info[@name='Type']/string()"}
```

But now it's hard-coded :(

So what I am trying to do is get the name of the stream and then associate it with a type. steam 0 is video, stream 1 is audio, stream 6 is subtitle and so on.

Cheers :)

Comment: OK I found out that I can use this
`XmlRole{ name: "type"; query: "information/category[2]/@name/string()"}` but that is still not dynamic enough

Comment: Using [starts-with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698458/xpath-using-starts-with-function) you can select all the categories whose attribute `name` starts with "Stream" (just use `@name` as first parameter of the function). Hope that helps.