# Navigating in html by xpath in python

Tags: python, xpath

So, I am accessing some url that is formatted something like the following:

```
<DOCUMENT>
 <TYPE>A
 <SEQUENCE>1
 <TEXT>
  <HTML>
   <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" LINK=BLUE  VLINK=PURPLE>
   </BODY>
  </HTML>
 </TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>

<DOCUMENT>
 <TYPE>B
 <SEQUENCE>2
 ...
```

As you can see, it starts a document, (which is the sequence number 1), and then finishes the document, and then document with sequence 2 starts and so on.

So, what I want to do, is to write an xpath address in python such that to just get the document with sequence value 1, (or, equivalently, TYPE A).

I supposed that such a thing would work:

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
page = html.fromstring(pagehtml)
type_a = page.xpath("//document[sequence=1]/descendant::*/text()")
```

however, it just gives me an empty list as type_a variable.

Could someone please let me know what is my mistake in this code? I am really new to this xml stuff.

Comment: What you have as input is neither HTML nor XML of any kind. Did you write it yourself?

Comment: @MathiasMüller: No, I did not indeed! Here is an example of such urls that I am trying to crawl in:
http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/21344/000104746909001875/0001047469-09-001875.txt
It is a pretty long one, so that was why I did not include it in my question.

Answer (score 3):

It might be because that's highly dubious HTML. The `<SEQUENCE>` tag is unclosed, so it could well be interpreted by lxml as containing *all* of the code until the next `</DOCUMENT>`, so it does not end up just containing the `1`. When your XPath code then looks for a `<SEQUENCE>` containing `1`, there isn't one.

Additionally, XML is case-sensitive, but HTML isn't. XPath is designed for XML, so it is also case sensitive, which would also stop your `document` matching `<DOCUMENT>`.

Try `//DOCUMENT[starts-with(SEQUENCE,'1')]`. That's based on [Xpath using starts-with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698458/xpath-using-starts-with-function/).

Ideally, if the input is under your control, you should instead just close the type and sequence tags (with `</TYPE>` and `</SEQUENCE>`) to make the input valid.

Comment: This is the first time I've actually used Python or XPath, so this is based on experience of HTML/XML only.

Comment: +1 "highly dubious HTML" - exactly. And yes, XPath is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GKFX. I do agree that it is an odd one. Unfortunately, I dont have control over the code. [ I provided a link in the comments of the question ]
Unfortunatey, your code did not work as well. It is odd, because xpath recognizes sequence as a node, so that when I put ://sequence/descendant::*/text() it recognizes the correct place. but as you mentioned it does not get when it is finished

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out, apart from the great answer provided by @GKFX, `lxml.html` module is capable of parsing broken or a fragment of HTML. In fact it will parse from your string just fine and handle it well.

> fromstring(string): Returns document_fromstring or
>   fragment_fromstring, based on whether the string looks like a full
>   document, or just a fragment.

The problem you have, perhaps from your other codes generating the string, also lies on the fact that, you haven't given the true path to access the `SEQUENCE` node.

```
type_a = page.xpath("//document[sequence=1]/descendant::*/text()")
```

your above xpath will try to find all `document` nodes with a following children node called `sequence` which its value **1**, however your `document`'s first children node is `type`, not `sequence`, so you will never get what you want.

Consider rewriting to this, will get what you need:

```
page.xpath('//document[type/sequence=1]/descendant::*/text()')
['A\n ', '1\n ']
```

Since your html string is missing the closing tag for `sequence`, you cannot, however get the correct result by another xpath like this:

```
page.xpath('//document[type/sequence=1]/../..//text()')
['A\n ', '1\n ', 'B\n ', '2']
```

That is because your `sequence=1` has no closing tag, `sequence=2` will become a child node of it.

I have to point out an important point that your html string is still invalid, but the tolerance from `lxml`'s parser can handle your case just fine.

Comment: thanks a lot, @Anzel. but still no chance. your code gives me [] as well

Comment: @novice_007, well it works fine on my machine, that leads me to believe your html parser may be broken somehow. Are you sure you have the `libxml2` installed? You can check with `python -c "import libxml2"` and see if it throws an error

Answer (score 1):

Try <strike>using a relative path:</strike> explicitly specifying the correct path to your element. (not skipping `type`)

```
page.xpath("//document[./type/sequence = 1]")
```

See: http://pastebin.com/ezQXtKcr

Output:

```
Trying original post (novice_007): //document[sequence=1]/descendant::*/text()
[]
Using GKFX's answer: //DOCUMENT[starts-with(SEQUENCE,'1')]
[]
My answer: //document[./type/sequence = 1]
[<Element document at 0x1bfcb30>]
```

Currently, the xpath I provided is the only one that `... to just get the document with sequence value 1`

Comment: How is that path expression more relative than the one in the OP?